# Can we have an empty base path?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Can we have an empty basepath for @Path annotation? 
ie. @Path("/")

I want to provide REST api http://servername/abc

```
@Path("")
public class YourResource {

  @Path("/abc")
  @GET
  public Responce method1(){
    return Response.ok("ok").build();
  }

}
```

When I do this, exception is thrown

javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)

UPDATE - I bind in my GuiceServletContextListener like below

> bind(YourResource.class).in(Singleton.class);
>
> serve("/abc").with(GuiceContainer.class);

Comment: Of course. Leave the base path fully empty and you will get what you want.

Comment: I tried @Path(""), and still get the same error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Remove `@Path("/")` annotation completely from class</s>

and

**prefix** slash (**/**) into the method level path annotation, like `@Path("/abc")`

Please verify whether your URI is mapped to java method as below.

While starting your server, you can see how the URI's mapped into the java methods, something like this in **eclipse console**...

`Mapped "{[/static/transit],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<com.xxx.yyy.zzz.domain.Transit> com.xx.yy.zz.controller.abcDataController.getAllTransit()`

==================================================================

**UPDATE:**

According to the java doc below, There are **no difference** between these 2 examples, both will work.
Either you can **use leading** slash with **both** URIs or **don't use any leading** slash with **both** URIs, both are **same.**

> Paths are relative. For an annotated class the base URI is the
>   application path, see ApplicationPath. For an annotated method the
>   base URI is the effective URI of the containing class. For the
>   purposes of absolutizing a path against the base URI , a leading '/'
>   in a path is ignored and base URIs are treated as if they ended in
>   '/'.

```
@Path("message")

public class MessageServices {

    @PUT
    @Path("sendsms")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response sendSms() {
        //....
    }

}
```

**OR**

```
@Path("/message")
public class MessageServices {

    @PUT
    @Path("/sendsms")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response sendSms() {
        //....
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried that. I get this exception.  "com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:8080/abc/"

Comment: Can you try like @Path("/test") at class level , and @Path("/abc") at method level? and use the uri : localhost:8080/test/abc

Comment: It is difficult to suggest without seeing your current code, please refer this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example/

Comment: updated my answer, accept/upvote this answer, if it helps

Comment: Refer the article - Jersey and Guice: a perfect combination for writing RESTful APIs; https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes//posts/jersey_guice_rest_api

Comment: @Sundaraj - `@Path` does not need to start with slash, it's prefixed by slash by jersey when the slash is not there

Answer (score 0):

add a slash to your path ("/"), like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class YourResource {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not working...
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found